# android seekbar and adjacent focusable widgets

Tags: android, focus, scrollbar, seekbar

I have a question about android sliders and adjacent focusable widgets.  First some background:

In a PC hScrollBar you can adjust the current 'value' with three methods:
1) dragging the thumb
2) click on the 'track' - thumb moves by large increment
3) click on arrows at either end - thumb moves by small increment
the last can be used for quick precision increments around an area of interest.

in an Android SeekBar you can adjust the current 'value' with three methods
1) dragging the thumb
2) click on the 'track' - thumb moves to click point
3) arrow keys - move thumb by set amount.

Sounds like a pretty close match.  **However**, the arrow keys are only permanently available on a device with a hardware keyboard.

Obviously, they may be found in some soft keyboards [not all], but it seems really messy to me to have that on display all the time, or else popping up when you touch the slider.

One obvious way round this would be to put buttons at each end of the slider and use them to increment the thumb position left or right.

However in the [android docs for seekbar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SeekBar.html)  I find this statement near the top '**Placing focusable widgets to the left or right of a SeekBar is discouraged**.'

THE Question:

I just can't find anything more about this statement.  Is this purely a cosmetic rule, or is there some practical reason behind it?

**[Edit]** I've just remembered that [buttons in touch mode are not focusable](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html) by default, so this 'rule' does not apply to them, so I could safely have 'arrow' buttons on either side of the seekbar.

However I shouldn't use focusable widgets like EditBoxes - I'd still like to know why that is so. **[/Edit]**